# Cast vs ToXXX for value handles in v8

Tags: javascript, c++, v8

I'm embedding V8 as an auxiliary language in a C++ program.

I retrieve a `Handle<Value>` from V8 when I call something like

```
Handle<Value> value_handle = context->Global()->Get(key_handle);
```

I can then find out that it is (say) a string with `value_handle->IsString()`. And if so I can convert it to a `Handle<String>` to access its string-specific methods.

But there seems to be two ways of doing that, either:

```
Handle<String> string = value_handle->ToString();
```

or

```
Handle<String> string = Handle<String>::Cast(value_handle);
```

However, for Arrays and Functions, there is no `toArray()` or `toFunction` methods, just the casting.

So my question is:
a) are the `ToXXX` just syntactic sugar for casting?
and, if not b) what is the `ToXXX` method doing?

Answer (score 9, accepted):

`ToXXX` functions perform type coercions as described in subsections of [section 9](http://es5.github.com/#x9) of ECMA-262 5th. For example `ToString` is described in [section 9.8](http://es5.github.com/#x9.8): when given a non-string value it'll return an appropriate string representation of it, if you are passing object it'll call `toString` method on it (or `valueOf` if `toString` is not present). Relevant code for `ToString`: in `api.cc` [`Value::ToString`](https://code.google.com/p/v8/source/browse/branches/bleeding_edge/src/api.cc?r=13706#2362) that calls into `runtime.js` [`ToString`](https://code.google.com/p/v8/source/browse/branches/bleeding_edge/src/runtime.js?r=11405#549)

On the other hand `Handle<XXX>::Cast(...)` does no coercions. It's just a type cast for handles. Essentially it is just a `static_cast<XXX*>`. In debug mode `Handle<T>::Cast(...)` is checked and aborts execution when types do not match. It would be a fatal error if you are given a `Handle<Value>` containing an `Object` and you are trying to cast it to a `Handle<String>`. In release mode casting to an incompatible type will just later lead to weird results and possibly crashes, when you try to use the result of the cast. Relevant code in `v8.h` [`Handle<T>::Cast`](https://code.google.com/p/v8/source/browse/branches/bleeding_edge/include/v8.h?r=13686#269) which delegates to (for example) [`String::Cast`](https://code.google.com/p/v8/source/browse/branches/bleeding_edge/include/v8.h?r=13686#4658) which checks the cast (if checks are enabled) via [`String::CheckCast`](https://code.google.com/p/v8/source/browse/branches/bleeding_edge/src/api.cc?r=13706#2503).

Comment: Hmm. Are you sure this is what really happens under the hood? I have some strange behavior where *sometimes* calling ToString() on a `Handle<Value>` results in a SEGFAULT if the `Value` is not a String. Other times, it will do what you describe.

Comment: @namuol yes I am sure. SEGFAULT can be caused by a variety of reasons ranging from a bug in your code to a bug in V8 code. Hard to say which without seeing the code in question.

Comment: It turns out that `ToString` actually needs to operate within a context -- I was calling it without setting up a context on a persistent handle. I solved it by storing the isolate the handle was created within with the value and created a context from the isolate before calling `ToString`.

Comment: +1, Weird! wrong Cast will not make a warning or exception. In my case, it did not even make program crash but give wrong result to users.

Answer (score 0):

We can locate

> V8EXPORT Local ToString() const;

in line 971 of `v8.h`
where V8EXPORT is a OS dependent approach for functions.

---

ToString of Handle of String is located at line 2362 of api.cc

```
Local<String> Value::ToString() const {
  i::Handle<i::Object> obj = Utils::OpenHandle(this);
  i::Handle<i::Object> str;
  if (obj->IsString()) {
    str = obj;
  } else {
    i::Isolate* isolate = i::Isolate::Current();
    if (IsDeadCheck(isolate, "v8::Value::ToString()")) {
      return Local<String>();
    }
    LOG_API(isolate, "ToString");
    ENTER_V8(isolate);
    EXCEPTION_PREAMBLE(isolate);
    str = i::Execution::ToString(obj, &has_pending_exception);
    EXCEPTION_BAILOUT_CHECK(isolate, Local<String>());
  }
  return Local<String>(ToApi<String>(str));
}
```

---

For consistency and take advantages from further upgrade of V8 versions, I strongly recommend to use toString() instead of the primitive cast.

Comment: No, this is the wrong ToString. The one you are pointing at is ReplacementStringBuilder::ToString. You should look at `api.cc` instead.

Comment: really! Sorry. Thanks @VyacheslavEgorov .I'd made a big mistake when searching.

Comment: Thanks Abby. Why do you think the ToString should be more future proof than casting? If I've verified that handle->IsString(), then my instinct is to prefer a cast.

Comment: both of the type changes are going to implement a reinterpret_cast at some point of stacks. however, ToString() is wrapped with V8 instance isolation to thread out the casting process. EXCEPTION_BAILOUT_CHECK will help handling the thread until callback returns, it protects the current thread but also keeping the synchronous property of casting.